# Rewrite URL and set redirect to rewritten URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am passing a country code in a parameter  and I wish to rewrite that url.
eg

www.website.com/deal.php?country_code=gb

to

www.website.com/gb

So far I have been able to rewrite it using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Match the first two groups before / and send them to the query string
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)?$ deal.php?country_code=$1 [L,R=301]
```

So I am able to access www.website.com/gb and it works but I can still access www.website.com/deal.php?country_code=gb. Ideally If I try to access www.website.com/deal.php?country_code=gb I would like it to redirect to /gb

How can I do this?

Comment: You will end up with a redirect loop if u do that

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think it's necessary to redirect requests for the long URL, but if you really want to do this then you must change the actual URL so that an infinite loop is not entered.

For instance, try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !new_path=true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} country_code=([a-zA-Z]{2})
RewriteRule ^deal\.php$ /%1? [R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})$ deal.php?country_code=$1&new_path=true
```

The first two RewriteCond directives check that `new_path=true` is not found in the query string, and that a country code is. If both of these are satisfied, then the first RewriteRule does a browser redirect to the preferred, short URL with an empty query string.

The final RewriteRule silently rewrites a request for a country code to the deal.php page and adds the `new_path=true` parameter so that an infinite loop is not entered.

Note that the patterns above only allow for a two-character country code. If you need to allow two and three-character country codes then change the relevent part of the pattern to `([a-zA-Z]{2,3})` instead.